# Number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic-progressions, pattern-recognition

I was wondering about sets that do not contain any $3$-term AP, and came to know that the official name of such a set is [Salem–Spencer set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem%E2%80%93Spencer_set). I was considering the question of counting the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ for a given $n$. This is listed in [OEIS A051013](https://oeis.org/A051013).

However, neither on OEIS, nor on anywhere else could I find any literature dealing with the specific question at hand. So, my question is whether anyone knows of any formula (recursive or otherwise) for the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ for a given $n$.

I tried my hand at a recursion technique and tried to use the fact that such a set either ends with $n$ or it doesn't. So, we have
$$T(n)=T(n-1) + S(n)$$
where $T(n)$ is the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ and $S(n)$ is the number of Salem–Spencer subsets of $\{1,2,3,\dots ,n\}$ containing $n$.

These $S(n)$'s are listed in [OEIS A334893](https://oeis.org/A334893) (with the specific cases listed in [OEIS A334892](https://oeis.org/A334892)) but there's no formula for these to be seen.

Even if an exact result is not available, I would like to know whether it is possible to get any asymptotic results or even any useful bounds$^{*}$. Even references which may be helpful are welcome.

$[^*]$ A set that avoids a $3$-AP is also a set that avoids three consecutive numbers, which is known to be the Tribonacci numbers. So, the term *useful bounds* is to be read as bounds better than this.

Also posted on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/464314/311366)

Answer (score 2):

Let $r_3(n)$ be the maximum size of a Salem-Spencer set of $[n]$. Then the number $N$ of Salem-Spencer set of $[n]$is trivially bounded by
$$2^{r_3(n)}\leq N \leq \sum_{k=1}^{r_3(n)} \binom{n}{k} \leq n^{r_3(n)}.$$
The lower bound is because any subset of a Salem-Spencer set is Salem-Spencer, so there are at least $2^{r_3(n)}$ such sets. The upper bounds is because any Salem-Spencer set has size at most $r_3(n)$.

In other words, we have
$$r_3(n) \ll \log_2 N \ll r_3(n) \log n.$$
With our current knowledge of $r_3(n)$, I think we cannot do much better. Indeed, the SOTA (state-of-the-art) bound for $r_3(n)$ is something like
$$\frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/9} n}} \geq_{\text{Kelley-Meka-Bloom-Sisask}} r_3(n) \geq_{\text{Behrend}} \frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/2} n}}.$$
where $c$ denotes some positive constant. Note that the lower and upper bounds are much further than a factor of $\log n$ apart! Thus, the best we can write down, without a major breakthrough on $r_3(n)$, is something like
$$\frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/9} n}} \geq \log_2 N \geq \frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/2} n}}$$
(I absorbed the $\log n$ into the denominator.)

For example, if you manage to prove something like
$$\log_2 N \geq \frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/3} n}}$$
then this would immediately imply (with a different constant $c$)
$$r_3(n) \geq \frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/3} n}}$$
which would probably net you a paper in the Annals :-)

Here is a list of results referenced:

Behrend's lower bound can be found in any standard textbook discussing Roth's theorem. See e.g. [here](http://www.epsilonsmall.com/resources/behrends-construction/behrend.pdf) or [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.0732.pdf).

[Kelley-Meka's paper.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2302.05537) (Proves $\frac{n}{2^{c\log^{1/11} n}} \geq r_3(n)$. not published, but all experts agree it is correct.)

[Bloom-Sisask's improvement.](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.02353) (not published. Replace $1/11$ with $1/9$.)

Comment: I have answered your concerns in the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot (+1)!